# Run script upon Xcode project creation?

Tags: xcode, script, automation

Is there a way to run a shell script upon creating an Xcode project? I plan to do this so that I can store the project in OneDrive, but use the shell script to make an alias in iCloud Drive. Is there a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Xcode documentation, perhaps https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-custom-scripts-during-a-build would be a useful starting point.

Comment: The article shows how to add build phases, not run script upon creation, so I can then create an alias.